# Software to change container formats of video files (remux), in batch mode

Tags: video, media-player, media-converter, file-format

For video transcoding, there a number of programs I use, depending on the situation. Some of the most frequent are

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), [mkv2vob](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mkv2vob), [Multi AVCHD](http://multiavchd.deanbg.com/), and [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

However, for changing container formats, without transcoding audio or video, I have only been able to find [mkvmerge](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html) for remuxing to the mkv container format, and mkv2vob, as well as [tsMuxer](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/tsMuxeR), for remuxing to the ts or m2ts container format.

For going to another container, like mp4, I am stuck with actually transcoding to mp4 in the aforementioned software.

**So what I am looking for is a program that can remux video to a number of different container formats, including mp4, in batch mode.**

The use case is for playing on some different set-top media players. Playstation3 will play just about anything except an mkv. My solution has been to remux to m2ts, but transport streams add ~10% to the filesize. I have a big hard drive, so its not a huge issue, but it seems needless. My parents have an older Western Digital media player (pre-WD TV) that will play a few formats, but really is happiest with an mp4.

This doesn't seem like a very tall order, but I haven't found one yet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ffmpeg is usually the a/v conversion's equivalent of '42' - the answer to everything.